# Replace values in df col - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aiming to replace values in a df column `Num`. Specifically:

- where `1` is located in `Num`, I want to replace preceding 0's with `1` until the nearest `Item` is `1` working backwards or backfilling.
- where `Num == 1`, the corresponding row in `Item` will always be 0.
- Also, `Num == 0` will always follow `Num == 1`.

Input and code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
            'Item' : [0,1,2,3,4,4,0,1,2,3,1,1,2,3,4,0],
            'Num' :  [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
             })

df['Num'] = np.where((df['Num'] == 1) & (df['Item'].shift() > 1), 1, 0) 

    Item  Num
0      0    0
1      1    0
2      2    0
3      3    0
4      4    0
5      4    1
6      0    0
7      1    0
8      2    0
9      3    0
10     1    0
11     1    0
12     2    0
13     3    0
14     4    1
15     0    0
```

intended output:

```
    Item  Num
0      0    0
1      1    1
2      2    1
3      3    1
4      4    1
5      4    1
6      0    0
7      1    0
8      2    0
9      3    0
10     1    0
11     1    1
12     2    1
13     3    1
14     4    1
15     0    0
```

Comment: Can you please edit your description to be clear. Saying *"where `Num == 1`, the corresponding row in Item will always be 0"* is wrong per the data you show. I think you mean "the next row will have `Item==0, Num==0`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create groups of the rows according to the two start and end conditions using [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html). Then we can group by this new column and sum over the `Num` column. In this way, all groups that contain a `1` in the `Num` column will get the value `1` while all other groups will get `0`.

```
groups = ((df['Num'].shift() == 1) | (df['Item'] == 1)).cumsum()

df['Num'] = df.groupby(groups)['Num'].transform('sum')
```

Result:

```
  Item  Num
0    0    0
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    4    1
5    4    1
6    0    0
7    1    0
8    2    0
9    3    0
10   1    0
11   1    1
12   2    1
13   3    1 
14   4    1
15   0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
for a, b in zip(df[df['Item'] == 0].index, df[df['Num'] == 1].index):
    df.loc[(df.loc[a+1:b-1, 'Item'] == 1)[::-1].idxmax():b-1, 'Num'] = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't quite work on my dataset. I just edited my dummy df to display this.